# Execute in console the add of an URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Let's say the path is subdomain.domain.com/username what can I do, using javascript, to execute in console everything extra?

Ex: The normal path: subdomain.domain.com/username
If accessed subdomain.domain.com/username?something-9732422348-2 , execute in console the part something-9732422348-2.

Comment: why  you trying to do this in the console?

Comment: I'm just trying to automate a process of an website.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: your question is a bitt confusing, are you just trying to navigate to a url?, what is the process your tyring to replicate?

Comment: @trincot On a website (with profiles and stuff that allows you to use js, css, html as custom code) if you type a certain javascript command in console, it will give you images (that are grantable and free) from users. I would like to create a script to get the part from URL and give the people the desired image, without having to leave my profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate url by `split()` in your case by separator `"?"`

> str.split([separator[, limit]])

Your path `subdomain.domain.com/username` allways will be first item in array

```
var x = "subdomain.domain.com/username?something-9732422348-2"
x=x.split("?")
console.log(x) //["subdomain.domain.com/username", "something-9732422348-2"]
```

To take only params with out path u can remove it by `splice()`

> array.splice(start, deleteCount)

```
var x = "subdomain.domain.com/username?something-9732422348-2"
x=x.split("?")
x.splice(0,1)
console.log(x) //["something-9732422348-2"]
```

Comment: **From Review**: This answer was flagged as **low quality**. While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)